# Pairing of electrons in Nickel in presence of strong ligand(tetrahedral)

Tags: coordination-compounds

For tetrahedral CFSE, Nickel's last 6 electrons will go in the t2g set of orbitals. Since it is already the higher energy orbital, pairing should NOT happen right? However, all internet sources I found for NiCN4 show that pairing happens in the t2g. Shouldn't electrons not pair and follow hunds rule?
[image: Isn't this wrong? Electrons should not be able to pair and would follow general hund's rule]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have $t_{2g}$ or for that matter even $t_2$ (there's a "g", meaning centrally symmetric, only if the coordination geometry has that symmetry). You don't have a tetrahedral coordination at all.

When you have a $d^8$ central core with a strong field ligand, both crystal field theory and ligand field theory predict that a strong extra stabilization occurs by going to a square planar configuration, and so it generally does. $\ce{Ni(CN)4^{2-}}$ is actually a classic example of such a square planar coordination.

This square planar coordination no longer has the right symmetry to give a $t_2$ set and an $e$ set; instead the orbitals split in an entirely different way with the net result that one of the orbitals is much more destabilized than all the others. From https://www.jove.com/science-education/11462/crystal-field-theory-tetrahedral-and-square-planar-complexes:

[image]

Then the eight electrons go into the four lower-energy orbitals where perforce they are all paired.